# How to Run AMP and GTM locally

Tags: google-tag-manager, amp-html

Is it possible to run and debug Google Tag Manager for Accelerated Mobile Pages on local host? I see it doesn't work by default.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager requires a script and an iframe.

While AMP allows you to [embed iframes](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-iframe/amp-iframe.md), it does not allow javascript. From [specs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec):

> While it does allow styling the document using custom CSS, it does not
>   allow author written JavaScript beyond what is provided through the
>   custom elements to reach its performance goals.

You can use, however, Analytics. See [this section](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components#ads-and-analytics) for more info. Depending on your goals with GTM, you could achieve similar results with the amp-pixel or amp-analytics.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a GTM container & plug it to AMP page using AMP-analytics tag . Check the browser's network tab on the specific events.